# TFS Online build server post build scripts not available

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

According to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicktrog/archive/2015/03/05/adding-gulp-to-visual-studio-online-builds.aspx), there is an option to add powershell scripts to the build via a post build script path property.

> To invoke our script for front-end build tasks (clientcompile.bat), we
>   need to configure the build process. Open the ‘Process’ tab and expand
>   section ‘5. Advanced’ inside the Build section. Specifically we’re
>   going to provide the ‘Post-build script’ information. The script will
>   be executed on the build infrastructure after the source code has been
>   compiled, hence post-build.

I'm using TFS Online and I only have 3 sections, '3. Advanced' and no option to enter post-build script information.

[image]

How can I get this option available? Is it available on the online TFS build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build process parameters are surfaced by the build process template. Build process templates in existing projects don't get upgraded because of the potential to break customizations, that's why you're not seeing the new parameters. To get the new build process template, you could create a new team project, create a new build definition and download it from the process tab. Alternatively, I've [uploaded it here](https://gist.github.com/jimlamb/2d41ae794eea6a0ef0f5).

Once you've grabbed the updated build process template, you can follow [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx#template_use) to create a new build definition that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select the DefaultTemplate.12.xaml from the list at the top of the Process Page. In VSO the templates are no longer stored in source control and should be visable in the list.

If not you might need to update to Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: DefaultTemplate.12.xaml is not an option I have (I do have TFvcTemplate.12.xaml that looks like what I'm looking for though)

Comment: That's the one that you should use.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `Team Foundation Version Control` with which the following build process templates are available.

1. Default Template (DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml)
2. Upgrade Template (UpgradeTemplate.xaml)
3. AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml
4. LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml
5. TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml
6. TFvcTemplate.12.xaml

The **TFvcTemplate.12.xaml** and **TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml** do have the post build script options as per my question. But there are quite a few other differences in the process template, so its not a simple case of adding a post build script to the Default Template.

For further information the build process templates when using `Git` are different, they are.

1. Default Template (GitTemplate.12.xaml)
2. Upgrade Template (GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml)
3. GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml
4. GitTemplate.xaml
5. LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml